# What does 似てる似てない mean?

Tags: meaning

In this story, the speaker is trying to figure out the nature of a stranger's powers, he makes comparisons with the powers of an acquaintance but comes to the conclusion they're quite different. But before he comes to this conclusion he says:

> 似てる似てない以前の問題だ。

I'm not sure what the speaker is saying here, is someone could break it down for me that would be awesome.

Comment: Do you have a translation attempt? Also, please name the source if you can.

Answer (score 3):

似てる似てない is just 似ているか似ていないか or "whether they are similar or not similar". See [this recent question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56180/5010), too. For example 生きる死ぬの問題 is roughly the same as 生きるか死ぬかの問題 (a matter of life or death).

[～以前の問題 is a set phrase](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24561/5010), which in this context means the mentioned "problem" is not the actual problem. This sentence says they are so obviously different that it's not worth questioning or wondering if they are similar or not.